# How do I dim an imageview from an ImageAdapter Grid View class?

Tags: android, grid-layout

I am trying to create a logo quiz, which works, but I am unable to figure out how to modify a specific image from an ImageAdapter. Any guidance would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Here is my Quiz Activity:

```
public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
private InterstitialAd interstitial;
private static int SIZE = 50;
public static int location;
private int counter = 0;

// initialize buttons
public static ImageButton buttons[] = new ImageButton[SIZE];

// array names
public static String[] names = { "hannibal", "orphan black", "lord of the rings",
        "pretty little liars", "harry potter", "star trek",
        "the fault in our stars", "iron man", "thor", "frozen",
        "harry potter", "game of thrones", "hannibal", "doctor who",
        "sherlock", "attack on titan", "teen wolf", "game of thrones",
        "doctor who", "sherlock", "supernatural", "the hunger games",
        "american horror story", "breaking bad", "attack on titan",
        "teen wolf", "doctor who", "sherlock", "supernatural", "sherlock",
        "arrow", "the big bang theory", "mad men", "arrested development", 
        "game of thrones", "breaking bad", "sons of anarchy", "the graduate",
        "et", "scooby doo", "wizard of oz", "linux", "simpsons", "iron man", "wonder woman",
        "green lantern", "flash", "captain america", "thor", "the picture of dorian gray"


};

// array images
public int[] images = { R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5,
        R.drawable.image6, R.drawable.image7, R.drawable.image8,
        R.drawable.image9, R.drawable.image10, R.drawable.image11,
        R.drawable.image12, R.drawable.image13, R.drawable.image14,
        R.drawable.image15, R.drawable.image16, R.drawable.image17,
        R.drawable.image18, R.drawable.image19, R.drawable.image20,
        R.drawable.image21, R.drawable.image22, R.drawable.image23,
        R.drawable.image24, R.drawable.image25, R.drawable.image26,
        R.drawable.image27, R.drawable.image28, R.drawable.image29,
        R.drawable.image30,
        R.drawable.image31, R.drawable.image32, R.drawable.image33,
        R.drawable.image34, R.drawable.image35, R.drawable.image36,
        R.drawable.image37, R.drawable.image38, R.drawable.image39,
        R.drawable.image40,
        R.drawable.image41, R.drawable.image42, R.drawable.image43,
        R.drawable.image44, R.drawable.image45, R.drawable.image46,
        R.drawable.image47, R.drawable.image48, R.drawable.image49,
        R.drawable.image50};

GridView gridview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            //Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // PopUpActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, PopUpWindow.class);
            intent.putExtra("position", position);
            intent.putExtra("images", images);
            intent.putExtra("names", names);

            startActivity(intent);
            counter++;
            if (counter == 2) {
                counter = 0;
                // ad
                displayInterstitial();
            }
        }
    });

}

// Invoke displayInterstitial() when you are ready to display an
// interstitial.
public void displayInterstitial() {

    // Create ad request.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // Begin loading your interstitial.
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
    }
}

public void dimImage(){
   //item..setAlpha(300); <- This is where I am confused

}

}
```

And my ImageAdapter class:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4,
        R.drawable.image5, R.drawable.image6,
        R.drawable.image7, R.drawable.image8,
        R.drawable.image9, R.drawable.image10,
        R.drawable.image11, R.drawable.image12,
        R.drawable.image13, R.drawable.image14,
        R.drawable.image15, R.drawable.image16,
        R.drawable.image17, R.drawable.image18,
        R.drawable.image19, R.drawable.image20,
        R.drawable.image21, R.drawable.image22
};
```

Comment: dim means ?fade effect? --> `imageView.setAlpha(int)`

Comment: Yes, but how would I setAlpha for a specific item in my imageadapter?

Comment: in `getView` u get position right based on that u can put if condition and set it accordingly

Comment: you have define around 50 images array in activity and adapter only 22 images array so instead of create new images array in adapter pass from activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, random is correct. You can have your adapter keep track of which items have been dimmed, and check the setting of a particular item in getView:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private int mSize;
    private boolean [] mDim;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, int size) {
        mContext = c;
        mSize = size;
        mDim = new boolean[size];
    }

    public void dimImage(int position) {
        mDim[position] = true;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setAlpha(mDim[position] ? 0.5f : 1.0f);

        return imageView;
    }
}
```

In your activity, keep the adapter in a field, construct the adapter with SIZE, and when you want to dim an image, call adapter.dimImage(position), followed by notifyDataSetChanged:

```
public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
    private ImageAdapter adapter;
    private GridView gridview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, SIZE);
        gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
        ...
    }

    public void dimImage(){
        adapter.dimImage(location); // not sure if location represents the image index
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Awesome response, but at to which can I reference the ImageAdapter class? "adapter" is not recognized. Should I create another object? Thanks.

Comment: Sure. I've edited the answer, putting more of the activity code in place. Basically, your ImageAdapter is a handy object to make a field of your activity, so you can access it later when you are dimming one of the images.

Comment: Awesome, I got it working and I understand it now. Thank you so much. You are amazing :)